# Save multiple variables via Makefile

Tags: variables, makefile, gnu-make

So, within my make file I currently have

```
test1 := $(shell python script.py)
```

I want to return two variables from script.py. I tried:

```
test1,test2 := $(shell python script.py)
```

the above definitely does not work.

What would be best way to achieve the above?

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
test_all := $(shell python script.py)

test1 := $(word 1,$(test_all))
test2 := $(word 2,$(test_all))
```

Comment: So I tried the below but get 'No such file or directory'. ```all: 
test1 := $(word 1,$(test))
test2 := $(word 2,$(test)) ``` ```I ran: test="test one" make all```.

Comment: I can't understand what you did, because there's no way to provide a correctly formatted makefile in a comment.  You should edit your question and provide the makefile there, correctly formatted.  But note, my answer is meant to be taken verbatim.  In particular, it is _makefile_ code, not _shell_ code, and so it cannot appear inside the recipe of a rule (indented by TABs).  The recipe of a rule is always _shell_ syntax, and if you try to give it _makefile_ syntax you'll get errors such as the ones you suggest here.